# Google Places Api randomly stops working

Tags: google-maps

My google maps api works for about an hour and returns the correct results.  Then, after that hour, it just stops displaying results.

Answer (score 0):

google limits API queries to 1000/day. Is it possible that you have exceeded this limit?

[source](https://developers.google.com/places/policies#usage_limits)

Comment: no, i only search 68 times.  My app is still in development.  The API just stops working after about an hour.

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly what I found.  The limit is 150,000 per day IF YOU REGISTER A CC number.  Registered mine and POOF, it  started working.

**A console error or warning might be nice**, but you get nothing.  In chrome dev tools/network I could see traffic going to google on every keystroke, so I knew it was configured.

Comment: What is that "CC number"? You mean, enabling billing on your project? I have done that, set a limit of queries to 75,000, and it still is to be randomly stopping without any sign of error. I am using this wrapper: https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places